# ConcurrentModificationException with Iterators

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I've been coding a program and I've faced several issues that I was able to address properly. However, my program is throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` and I'm not sure what I can do.

I'm coding with NetBeans 8.0.2 to create a Java desktop application (as required by my professor).
The aim of the program is to manage a hotel. So, it has some parts like "Customers", "Staff" and "Booking" (the one giving me problems).

On each part, I have a `JTable` that uses a `DefaultTableModel`. In every part, I'm using files on the hard drive to make the changes persistent. I've coded new customer/staff classes. Now, I'm trying to code booking and unbooking methods. Everything has gone pretty well until I got to the "unbooking" part.

After the table and model I have an `ArrayList`. In this particular part, I have three of them:

- one for the whole table
- one containing only the free rooms
- one only with the already booked rooms.

The booking part was fine, I'm able to modify the table, the file and the `ArrayList` without any errors, and my program actually does what it should. But I'm unable to get the unbooking part to work. It should basically be the reverse of booking.

I will post a small part of my code, but if you need to know anything else or need some more parts of my code I would gladly share it.

**My code:**

```
public class GestionInstalaciones extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private final String ruta = System.getProperties().getProperty("user.dir");
    private final File archivo = new File (ruta+"\\Instalaciones.txt");
    private final DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    private final ArrayList contenidoInstalaciones;
    private final ArrayList contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas;
    private final ArrayList contenidoInstalacionesLibres;
    public GestionInstalaciones() {
       initComponents ();
       contenidoInstalaciones = new ArrayList();
       contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas = new ArrayList();
       contenidoInstalacionesLibres = new ArrayList();
       //Añadimos las columnas a la tabla.
       modelo.addColumn ("Tipo");
       modelo.addColumn ("Nombre Instalacion");
       modelo.addColumn ("NIF del Ocupante");
       cargarTabla();
}

private void cargarTabla(){
    this.contenidoInstalaciones.clear();
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    String tipo;
    String nombre;
    String NIFocupante;
    String[] partes;
    String linea;

    try{
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((linea=br.readLine())!=null) {
            //Adding info to general ArrayList
            this.contenidoInstalaciones.add(linea);
            //Splitting line into 3 components.
            partes = linea.split(",",3);
            tipo = partes[0];
            nombre = partes[1];
            NIFocupante = partes[2];

            //Skipping header.
            if ( tipo.equals( "Tipo" )) { continue; }

            //Añadimos la fila al modelo.
            modelo.addRow(partes);
        }
        TablaInstalaciones.setModel(modelo);
    }
    //Capturamos excepciones y cerramos fichero.
    catch(IOException e) {}
    finally { try { if ( null != fr ) { fr.close(); } } catch (IOException e2){ } }
}//end cargarTabla()

private void botonLiberarInstalacionActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
    Object linea;
    int contador=0;
    String aux; 
    String tiposATrabajar = "";
    String[] tiposAInsertar;
    Iterator instalacionesOcupadas;

    //Cleaning of already booked ArrayList.
    //this.contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas.clear();

    instalacionesOcupadas = contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas.iterator();
    this.comboTipoALiberar.removeAllItems();
    this.comboTipoALiberar.addItem("Seleccione");

    //Reading the general Table.
    for (int z = 0; z < TablaInstalaciones.getRowCount() ; z++) {
        //The booking parameter is on the 3rd place.
        if(!TablaInstalaciones.getValueAt(z,2).equals("")){
            //Putting the line into the ArrayList for booked rooms..
            linea = TablaInstalaciones.getValueAt(z,0) + "," + TablaInstalaciones.getValueAt(z,1) + "," + TablaInstalaciones.getValueAt(z,2);
            this.contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas.add(linea);
            contador++;
        }
    }

    **//Reading the booked ArrayList to put the right values on the combobox related. 
      //===> THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR !!!
    while(instalacionesOcupadas.hasNext()) {** 
        aux = instalacionesOcupadas.next().toString().split(",",3)[0];
        //Checking to add only 1 kind of each room type.
        if(!tiposATrabajar.contains(aux)); {
            if (tiposATrabajar.equals("")) { tiposATrabajar=aux; }
            else { tiposATrabajar = tiposATrabajar + "," + aux; }
        }
    }      
    //
    tiposAInsertar = tiposATrabajar.split(",");
    //Adding the type into the combobox.
    for (String elemento: tiposAInsertar){ this.comboTipoALiberar.addItem(elemento.replace(",","")); }

}
```

Comment: So the `while` loop condition is throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes, the while is the line that throws the Exception

Comment: If the contents of the `Collection` have changed since the last time you used the iterator, you will get an `Exception`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of the `Collection` you are iterating through have been changed since the last time you have used an iterator, you will get an exception if you try to use or reuse it. Create a new one - as a general rule, [don't reuse an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120615/7366707).

You are:

1. Creating an iterator
2. Modifying the list
3. Using the iterator after the list has been modified ← Error!

You should modify the list before creating the iterator.

Also, you should try to [minimize the scope of local variables](https://coderanch.com/t/638417/books/Effective-Java-Minimize-scope-local).

As opposed to:

```
Iterator<String> someIterator = strings.iterator();
while (someIterator.hasNext()) {
    doSomething();
}
```

You should probably do:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = strings.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Of course, if you (as you said) *do not need to* modify the list, use a for-each loop:

```
for (String s : strings) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Some unrelated points:

- Why are you writing things like `extends java.awt.JFrame`? [Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) it and use `JFrame` instead.
- Declare and initialize your variables when you need them. If you had initialized the `Iterator` *only* in front of your `for` loop you wouldn't have had this problem.
- Use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)! Non-generic `Collection`s will only err at run-time, while generic ones will give compile errors instead.

Comment: Dear @1blustone thanks for your time and effort. I will try to modify the code to use for s instead of while s ... and declare right in front (or even inside) the for as you told me. One quick question, reading the link you gave, this line of code Iterator<String> iterator = players.iterator(); ... is creating a new iterator based on another iterator called "players"? I will do some changes and I will come back. Thank you so so much!

Comment: @Magius in my example, `strings` is a sample list containing, well, `String`s. For your example it would probably be `Iterator instalacionesOcupadas = contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas.iterator();`. `iterator()` is simply a method of the [`Collection` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator--).

Comment: @Magius You did say you don't need to modify the list's contents, right? In that case just use a "for-each loop" - updated my answer.

Comment: I'm not adding nor deleting items, but I'm the last part of some items...

Comment: @Magius If you aren't modifying a list you don't necessarily need an iterator (you can use a normal index-based loop or a for-each loop)

Comment: Sorry @1blustone .... when I'm saying _I'm not modifying any item_, I'm trying to say that the general list which contains all elements does NOT increase or decrease its size. But particular lists containing booked // available rooms I DO modify the items... that's the reason to use ArrayList, because I need to increase/decrease the series with the user-hits.

Comment: @Magius you don't seem to be changing the list within that problematic `while`-loop

Comment: So @1blustone you're recommending me to move to normal arrays? Declaring it with size + 1 or size - 1 ?

Comment: @Magius no no no I just meant you don't need an iterator for that while loop, you could easily replace `while([something].hasNext())` with `for(Object aux : instalacionesOcupadas)`

Comment: @Magius I would really recommend making your `ArrayList` generic though because you don't need to specify `Object` as the type. For example `ArrayList<Booking>` instead of `ArrayList` (replace Booking with your class name that you want to be in the list)

Comment: I'm starting to get desperate @1blustone, since the good method that was working now results that is working pretty fine on the first iteration ... but on the second round is doing weird things (but not throwing errors). I will try that `for (Object aux : instalacionesOcupadas)` thing you told me. Thank you!!

Comment: @Magius what is the type of the objects in `instalacionesOcupadas`?

Comment: This is the declaration I made  `private final ArrayList contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas;`

Comment: @Magius yes, but what are you adding to the list? What class are the objects?

Comment: Objects: `this.contenidoInstalacionesOcupadas.add(linea);` being declared linea as `Object linea;`

Comment: Don't declare objects as only Object, declare them as the real type of the object. Are they Strings? what are these objects?

Comment: I need to have Strings, separated by any character (I've chosen `,` on this project). What's the point with declaring them particularly ?

Comment: @Magius this is the whole point of Java and other object-oriented languages - knowing the type of the objects. If you declared it as `String`, you wouldn't have had to write `instalacionesOcupadas.next().toString()`, you could have written `instalacionesOcupadas.next()` because it is already a `String`. Same with the lists. If you declare it as `ArrayList<String>` then the `get` method will return `String` and not `Object`. Your code is really in need of refactoring, please do so. Where did you learn to code like this?

Comment: Dear @1blustone ... you're completely RIGHT. This is my first re-approach to Java since I've been coding shell-scripts in the last 10 years. And I've forgotten most of the things I've ever learned. I'm declaring things without using. I'm declaring vars with Object and the parsing all the time to the needed ... I will code something and I will ping you back if I'm dumb enough to get myself in the same mess again. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

`ConcurrentModificationException`s happen when you make changes to a chain of elements (list) while you're actively looping through said chain.

I've encountered it often enough and always solve it by reverse looping through the list, that way you loop backwards and you can change or delete elements if you want without messing up the chain (list) you're looping over.

I'd provide you with code, but I find it very hard to read yours, so this'll have to do for now.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Dear @Roel Strolenberg Could you please give me some clue about that "reverse looping" you're talking about?

Comment: For instance: `for (int i = list.size()-1; i >= 0, i--)`. Hence looping backwards =)

Comment: Yep, that "pure reverse" lol
......... I mean, what's the point to go onward or backward if I'm not deleting anything? Just modifying / updating (without deleting in the process) any line...

Comment: It ensures you don't 'modify' the 'concurrent' list. The only reason you get the `ConcurrentModificationException` is because of you changing something in a collection you are looping over. In this case iterating. You can try `Collections.reverse(list)` before you iterate over it.